# How to immediately acknowledge a Pub/Sub message in a long-running program

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

I have an App Engine service running Python 3.7 (Standard Environment) that is a push subscriber to (and therefore triggered by) a Pub/Sub topic. This program can run for a long time. I need to be able to acknowledge the message immediately and then continue running, so that the service doesn't continuously receive the same message.

I see two possibilities here:

1. Ideally I would like to be able to acknowledge the message and then let the program run its course;
2. Alternatively, given that the service is idempotent, I could just let the service be barraged with the message, ignore all repeat messages, and then acknowledge once at the end of the program.

I think Option 1 seems more appealing- but I don't know if it's feasible in Python. As far as I know (please correct me if I'm wrong), the message gets acknowledged by the returned `200` status at the end.

I've put the basic skeleton to the program below. Any ideas are welcome, thanks!

```
@app.route('/_ah/push-handlers/receive_messages/', methods=['POST'])
def receive_messages_handler():
    if (request.args.get('token', '') != current_app.config['PUBSUB_VERIFICATION_TOKEN']):
        return 'Invalid request', 400

    envelope = json.loads(request.data.decode('utf-8'))
    payload = base64.b64decode(envelope['message']['data'])

    logging.info(f"Recieved message: {payload}")

    # Long-running program in here

    return 'OK', 200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to have a look on [cloud task](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/). It's designed for long running with retry policies

The design is the following:

- appengine consume the pubsub message, create the task and acknowledge the message (return 2xx)
- cloud task call appengine new endpoint for long running process.

Comment: I like this approach. I don't know if it really solves the original question, so anyone coming across this question in the future may or may not be satisfied with this, but because it solved my specific case I'm selecting it as the answer. Thanks!